# How to disable dropout while prediction in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using dropout in neural network model in keras. Little bit code is like

```
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(classes))
```

For testing, I am using `preds = model_1.predict_proba(image)`.

But while testing **Dropout** is also participating to predict the score which should not be happen. I search a lot to disable the dropout but didn't get any hint yet.

Do anyone have solution to disable the **Dropout** while testing in keras??

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Keras does this by default. In Keras dropout is disabled in test mode. You can look at the code [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/dc95ceca57cbfada596a10a72f0cb30e1f2ed53b/keras/layers/core.py#L109) and see that they use the dropped input in training and the actual input while testing.

As far as I know you have to build your own training function from the layers and specify the training flag to predict with dropout (e.g. its not possible to specify a training flag for the predict functions). This is a problem in case you want to do GANs, which use the intermediate output for training and also train the network as a whole, due to a divergence between generated training images and generated test images.

Answer (score 20):

As previously stated, dropout in Keras happens only at train time (with proportionate weight adjustment during training such that learned weights are appropriate for prediction when dropout is disabled).

This is not ideal for cases in which we wish to use a dropout NNET as a probabilistic predictor (such that it produces a distribution when asked to predict the same inputs repeatedly).  In other words, Keras' Dropout layer is designed to give you regularization at train time, but the "mean function" of the learned distribution when predicting.

If you want to retain dropout for prediction, you can easily implement a permanent dropout ("PermaDropout") layer (this was based on suggestions made by F. Chollet on the [GitHub discussion area for Keras](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1606)):

```
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras import backend as K

def PermaDropout(rate):
    return Lambda(lambda x: K.dropout(x, level=rate))
```

By replacing any dropout layer in a Keras model with "PermaDropout", you'll get the probabilistic behavior in prediction as well.

```
# define the LSTM model
n_vocab = text_to_train.n_vocab

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_vocab*4, 
          input_shape=input_shape, 
          return_sequences=True))
# Replace Dropout with PermaDropout
# model.add(Dropout(0.3)
model.add(PermaDropout(0.3))
model.add(LSTM(n_vocab*2))
# Replace Dropout with PermaDropout
# model.add(Dropout(0.3)
model.add(PermaDropout(0.3))
#model.add(Dense(n_vocab*2))
model.add(Dense(n_vocab, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 5):

To activate dropout for inference time u simply have to specify `training=True` in the layer of interest (`Dropout` in our case):

with `training=False`

```
inp = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Dropout(0.3)(inp, training=False)
x = Dense(1)(x)
m = Model(inp,x)
# m.compile(...)
# m.fit(...)

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1,10))

output = []
for i in range(0,100):
    output.append(m.predict(X)) # always the same
```

with `training=True`

```
inp = Input(shape=(10,))
x = Dropout(0.3)(inp, training=True)
x = Dense(1)(x)
m = Model(inp,x)
# m.compile(...)
# m.fit(...)

X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1,10))

output = []
for i in range(0,100):
    output.append(m.predict(X)) # always different
```

**by default, training is set to False**

**[HERE](https://towardsdatascience.com/extreme-event-forecasting-with-lstm-autoencoders-297492485037)** a full example of the usage of droput at inference time

Comment: Can you add any more detail about how this works? I also saw this in your extremely helpful NN-LSTM post on medium. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Drew, thanks! This simple line of code only allows dropout activation in your network after training (your predictions will be different every times!). Through this trick in Keras is possible to estimate prediction uncertainty usig bootstrapping iterating predictions. To go deep in the theory I suggest you to take a look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.01907.pdf and the relative references about the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Dropout removes certain neurons form play, and to compensate for that we usually take one of two ways.

1. scaling the activation at test time
2. inverting the dropout during the training phase

And keras uses the second form of correction as you can see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/dc95ceca57cbfada596a10a72f0cb30e1f2ed53b/keras/layers/core.py#L109)

Answer (score 3):

As newer Tensorflow versions are usually eager, you can try things like:

```
train_prediction = model_or_layer(input_data_numpy, training=True)
test_prediction = model_or_layer(input_data_numpy, training=False)
```

This will give you predictions considering the behavior of the desired phase.
For custom training loops (where instead of `model.fit` you make the eager predictions and apply the gradients yourself), it's important to use this:

```
#training
for batchX, batchY in data_generator:
    with with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
       train_outputs = model(batchX, training=True)
       loss = some_loss(batchY, train_outputs)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))

#validating
for batchX, batchY in val_generator:
    val_outputs = model(batchX, training=False)
    #calculate metrics
```

---

I never tested the following, but in non-eager mode, you can also probably build a new model using the existing layers, but passing `training=False` to the call (functional API model):

```
#if using an existing layer
output_symbolic_tensor = someExistingLayer(input_symbolic_tensor, training=True) 

#if you're creating a new layer now
output_symbolic_tensoe = SomeLayer(*layer_params)(input_symbolic_tensor, training=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Dropout layer has a call argument named 'training', when you use `model.fit`, Keras sets automatically this argument to `true`, and when you call model and use `model(input)`, Keras sets this argument to `false`.

You can use this argument in [custom layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) and [models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models) to control Dropout manually. See [Keras's official documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. This happens if you use a dropout layer.
2. If you have trained the model without validation data , model does not save in the checkpoint location.

3)if 1) and 2) is correct and if you save model using this approach "model.save('model_name.h5')" , the randomness of the dropout is preserved during prediction and hence different result every time. :-)

Comment: The above doesn't work this on worked for me ,  Thanks to GPT                                                           
import os
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'                
                                                                                                                                         
import tensorflow as tf
                                                                                                               tf.random.set_seed(30)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).